# Add a linebreak after a fixed sequence in a text field

Tags: qgis

I have text field that contains data in this format

```
1001.01:abcdefgh.1001.02:abcdefghijkl.1001.03:abcdefghfsdqfs.
```

I would like to insert an automatic line break so the result would be this :

```
1001.01:abcdefgh.
1001.02:abcdefghijkl.
1001.03:abcdefghfsdqfs.
```

other example with a field contains this

```
1245.01:qsdfqsdf.1245.02:qdfqsdmkj.1245.03:dfsdmfjmdf
```

I need that

```
1245.01:qsdfqsdf
1245.02:qdfqsdmkj.
1245.03:dfsdmfjmdf
```

So basically I need a way to insert a `/n` at the beginning of each
`xxxx.xx` (**x** always being a number)

Comment: Where exactly? To the field itself, to a new field or just in labeling?

Comment: And what exactly is your fixed sequence? Any string of a-z characters? Or `.1001`?

Comment: this should apply to all values contained in this field.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This regular expression will gave you the expected result :

```py
regexp_replace(
    "your_field",
    '(\\d{4}[.]\\d{2})',
    '\n\\1'
)
```

It will insert a `\n` even for the first occurence, so first characters in your examples. If you want to avoid that the expression will be :

```py
regexp_replace(
    "your_field",
    '(.)(\\d{4}[.]\\d{2})',  -- (point `.` here means any single character)
    '\\1\n\\2'
)
```

Comment: just edited my question!

Comment: two things : 1) god, I love code. 2) you're the man!